# Translations for each model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation

In my domain, many models have names, descriptions, etc. These properties need translations. I know how to represent this in a database. However I struggle finding a way to represent this with Rails.

```
|-------translations-table--------|
|translation_id|locale|translation|
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

|----------------------modelx-table---------------------|
|id|name_translation_id|description_translation_id|price|
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯

|-------modely-table--------|
|id|name_translation_id|date|
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create extra models for translations, yo just need to set up locales in .yml format, check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for further instructions

### Update

Ok now I understood your point, you want to add translatable fields on your entities/models, so users can manage those translations through a UI right?, well your approach is correct, however there is a gem called [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) that does the exact same thing but with more toys, and much more standardized as you want.

Comment: What I did was add a model Translation (with only an id) and a model TranslationRecord (with an id, a translation_id and a locale). Then I added a name_translation and a description_translation "belongs_to :class_name => 'Translation'" relationship to the Product model. There might be a more standard way to do it, but I couldn't find it. If you use an .yml file, there's no way to administer your product names and descriptions in different languages. Feel free to post the correct way of adding dynamic translations in Rails, otherwise I'll answer with my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I eventually came up with:

```
#Models
class Translation
   has_many :translation_records
end

class TranslationRecord
    (translation_records.find_by :locale => I18n.locale).text
end

class ModelX
    belongs_to :name_translation, :class_name => 'Translation'
    belongs_to :description_translation, :class_name => 'Translation'

    def name
        name_translation.current
    end

    def description
        description_translation.current
    end
end

#Migrations
class CreateTranslationRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
        create_table :translation_records do |t|
            t.references :translation
            t.string :locale
            t.string :text
        end

        add_index :translation_records, :locale
    end
end

class CreateTranslation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
        create_table :translations do |t|
            # only id column
        end
    end
end

class AddTranslationToModelXs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
        add_reference :model_xs, :name_translation
        add_reference :model_xs, :description_translation
    end
end
```